# Regex for Linux file permissions (numeric notation)

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I can't for the life of me figure out the proper regex for this.

What I'm looking for is a regex to match a valid numeric representation of Linux file permissions (e.g. 740 for all-read-none, 777 for all-all-all). So far I've tried the following:

```
strtotest=740
echo "$strtotest" | grep -q "[(0|1|2|3|4|5|7){3}]"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "found it"
fi
```

The problem with the above is that the regex matches anything with `1-5` or `7` in it, regardless of any other characters. For example, if `strtotest` were to be changed to `709`, the conditional would be true. I've also tried `[0|1|2|3|4|5|7{3}]` and `[(0|1|2|3|4|5|7{3})]` but those don't work as well.

Is the regex I'm using wrong, or am I missing something that has to deal with `grep`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest and most obvious regexp which is going to work for you is:

```
grep -q '(0|1|2|3|4|5|7)(0|1|2|3|4|5|7)(0|1|2|3|4|5|7)'
```

Here is an optimized version:

```
grep -Eq '(0|1|2|3|4|5|7){3}'
```

since 6 can represent permissions as well, we could optimize it further:

```
grep -Eq '[0-7]{3}'
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I wish I could + rep a few people, but I guess I need to be a bit more active on this site in order to do so :P

Comment: `grep -Eq "[(0|1|2|3|4|5|7)]{3}"` (and its longer cousin) that you posted in your answer is actually incorrect. `[ ]` defines a range, so your regex would match say `||9`, `77)` among others.

Comment: Corrected the regular expressions, as this is the accepted answer and the one most likely to be seen.

Answer (score 7):

what you want is probably

```
grep -Eq "[0-7]{3}"
```

edit:
if you're using this for finding files with certain permissions, you should rather have a look at [`find`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php) (`-perm`) or [`stat`](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/stat.1.php)

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing this as a learning exercise. I'm using it in a BASH shell that, when executed and fed a permission, will change permissions for all files and sub directories within it to the given permission.

Answer (score 3):

1. Your regex is very broken: `[` `]` define a range, and all characters in it are in the set that is allowed.
2. grep has some extra quoting rules that may require extra `\`.
3. grep searches for your regex within each line - if you want to only match at the start of the line you need `^` as the first char in the regex, and if you want to match to the end of the line you need a `$` at the end of the regex.

Comment: Oh, fail on my part. I was under the false assumption that the brackets were something grep needed for regexps.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference, you can do it with shell pattern in Bash

```
if [[ $strtotest == [0-7][0-7][0-7] ]]; then
    echo "Found it"
fi
```

Comment: +1 for both addressing the problem with the regular expression AND eliminating the explicit comparison of `$?`.