# Using Regex to determine if linux files perms are default or "more secure"

Tags: regex, linux, file-permissions

I've found a few topics on this - the most relevant so far here ([Regex for Linux file permissions (numeric notation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419023/regex-for-linux-file-permissions-numeric-notation)) but still not quite getting this...

I want to use a regex to determine when a files permission is "more secure" or alternatively "less secure" than a pre-defined default.

Example: I expect a default of 644, but 640, and even 600 is "ok" because it is actually more secure than 644.

The opposite approach would be to match any files with a security "less secure" than 644, so 677, 607, etc would match on this condition.

Im thinking more/less secure might be too subjective (ex. is 744 more, less or same as 644 in this context since only the "owner" actually has elevated perms)? Is regex the wrong way to approach this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should look at the `-perm` parameter of the `find` command to select files with the permissions you want.

Comment: What language do you want to achieve this? Regex may be ok for extracting numbers but then you have to compare them anyway. Also, it's not clear what is "more secure": for instance, is 0700 more or less secure than 0001? Or how about 0004? Or 0002?